# Is there a way to associate proprieties to chat messages using Redis?

Tags: redis, predis

I am trying to build a chat room and I want to store additional information like: nickname, time and avatar then associate them to a message.

I might use ':' to separate between some properties but it doesn't sound like an elegant way!

```
$list = "message_history";
$message = $data['nickname'] . ':' . $data['message'];
Redis::lpush($list, $message);
```

Is there an elegant way to do so using Redis ?

Comment: what if your message or nickname contain `:` ? Also didn't see time and avatar in the value list ? What about the putting all chatroom messages in a single list ? how are you going to decide which message belongs to which chat room ?

Comment: I might prevent users using colons in their nick name and it's okay for the messages as I know how many properties I'll have before. Also, I only have one public chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a hash 'hset'. And by giving each message an id and save them in a separate list I could access all the messages through that list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in your comments, you will have a single chat room, `redis lists` work for a chat room.

- The elements will be `sorted in insertion order` (good for timeline of chat)
- A single list supports more than 4 billion of elements (probably more than enough)
- You may use `LPUSH`/`RPUSH` to add new message, and since Redis lists are implemented with `linked lists`, both adding a message to the beginning or end of the list is same, O(1), which is great.
- Use LRANGE to paginate messages with `start` and `end`. it wouldn't be beneficial to get all messages at once, you may have possible memory, network related problems, Careful about using `LRANGE` for large list with high offset from either side.
- If you are going to keep only last n messages(depending on your business rules) in the list then you may use `LTRIM`.
- I don't think you will need a specific message for public chatroom, because `LINDEX` is O(n) (except first and last). if you are going to need, consider it carefully.

> This is the [benchmark](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) for LRANGE from official redis documentation;

- LRANGE (first 100 elements): 42123.00 requests per second
- LRANGE (first 300 elements): 15015.02 requests per second
- LRANGE (first 450 elements): 10159.50 requests per second
- LRANGE (first 600 elements): 7548.31 requests per second

Edit:

In your case you may push elements in `username:avatar:time:message format` and parse it when you need to display. You consider to save users in a hash structure, and and save all user related properties in hashes and create messages in `userId:time:message` format. both options seems fine.

Comment: Thank you Ersoy for conforming my way, for tthe nice explanation and the benchmark. But I'll just wait to see if there's some other way !